# Draw line in picturebox and redraw on zoom

Tags: c#, winforms, draw, picturebox, lines

I'm drawing a line in a picturebox this way:

```
horizontalstart = new Point(0, e.Y); //Start point of Horizontal line.
horizontalend = new Point(picbox_mpr.Width, e.Y); //End point of Horizontal line.
verticalstart = new Point(e.X, 0); //Start point of Vertical line
verticalend = new Point(e.X, picbox_mpr.Height); //End point of Vertical line.
```

Then on the paint event I do this:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(redline, horizontalstart, horizontalend); //Draw Horizontal line.
e.Graphics.DrawLine(redline, verticalstart, verticalend); //Draw Vertical line.
```

Pretty simple, now, my image can zoom and here's where I struggle..

How do I keep the line in the same spot that was drawn even if I zoom the image?

Comment: a good way to simplify the code is to look into graphics transformations. It can be a little difficult to undestand at first if you are not good at math, but once you get the basics, code for zooming, moving and scaling becomes very readable and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing an absolute integer coordinate, store a decimal value representing the "percentage" of that coord with respect to the width/height of the image.  So if the X value was 10 and the width was 100, you store 0.1.  Let's say the image was zoomed and it was now 300 wide.  The 0.1 would now translate to 0.1 * 300 = 30.  You can store the "percentage" X,Y pairs in PointF() instead of Point().

Here's a quick example to play with:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private List<Tuple<PointF, PointF>> Points = new List<Tuple<PointF, PointF>>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);

        this.pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        this.pictureBox1.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(pictureBox1_SizeChanged);
        this.pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_Paint);
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // convert absolute points:
        Point ptStart = new Point(100, 25);
        Point ptEnd = new Point(300, 75);

        // to percentages:
        PointF ptFstart = new PointF((float)ptStart.X / (float)pictureBox1.Width, (float)ptStart.Y / (float)pictureBox1.Height);
        PointF ptFend = new PointF((float)ptEnd.X / (float)pictureBox1.Width, (float)ptEnd.Y / (float)pictureBox1.Height);

        // add the percentage point to our list:
        Points.Add(new Tuple<PointF, PointF>(ptFstart, ptFend));
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // increase the size of the picturebox 
        // watch how the line(s) change with the changed picturebox
        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(pictureBox1.Width + 50, pictureBox1.Height + 50);
    }

    void pictureBox1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Tuple<PointF, PointF> tup in Points)
        {
            // convert the percentages back to absolute coord based on the current size:
            Point ptStart = new Point((int)(tup.Item1.X * pictureBox1.Width), (int)(tup.Item1.Y * pictureBox1.Height));
            Point ptEnd = new Point((int)(tup.Item2.X * pictureBox1.Width), (int)(tup.Item2.Y * pictureBox1.Height));
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, ptStart, ptEnd);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post an example? Thanks!